# Как в laravel конвертировать array в xml?

Tags: php, laravel

Как конвертировать array из модели в xml средствами laravel ?

Контроллер:

```
$data = App\Test::test();
```

Модель:

```
public static function test(){
  return static::where('id','>',0)->orderBy('id');
}
```

Есть ли аналог метода из Yii Response::FORMAT_XML ?

Comment: Это подходит? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml

Comment: @TotalPusher нет конечно, интересует именно средствами laravel.

Comment: Чем не устраивает?

Comment: @TotalPusher например тем, что из "коробки" существует метод для работы с json :
response()->json , вопрос и заключался в том, что умеет ли laravel делать тоже самое с xml

Comment: @VadimPopov, из коробки такого точно нет, по крайней мере пока что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Маловероятно, что найдешь из коробки. Бери это https://github.com/spatie/array-to-xml

Comment: Конечно не хотелось бы для такой цели, подключать библиотеку к проекту, но видимо выход такой - писать своё решение или использовать то, что прислали вы. Спасибо